# How to compare two objects by members that might have floating point values and do not have a proper equals?

Tags: java, floating-point, equals

I have a library of domain objects that is generated (and outside my direct control). In this library the following object resides:

```
public class SomeObject {
    public float someField;
    public boolean equals(SomeObject cmp) {
        if(someField != cmp.someField) 
            return false;
        return true;
    }
}
```

I want to compare `SomeObject` instance with a given tolerance (or a similar "imprecise" method). Is there a library available for JAVA that does this already?

Additionally I'm looking for nullSafe implementations.

I've checked out Spring's ObjectUtils and JAVA 7's Objects and Apache's commons-lang, these do a bit-wise comparison of floats instead of supplying me with an epsilon.

**EDIT**
I do not expect the library to choose the tolerance, since that would require knowledge of the application specifics. But if I *know* the value for tolerance a function like this could exist?

`public boolean equals(Object o1, Object o2, double toleranceToUseForThisComparison)`

Comment: Choosing the correct epsilon depends very much on what's already happened in your computation (errors accumulate). So I doubt there is a credible library that satisfies this.

Comment: Are you wanting code that considers two objects "equal" if the difference between their float fields is within a specified delta? Also, note that this class does not override the equals method of Object - the parameter type should be `Inject` to do that.

Comment: Yes, two objects are equal when their members are within a given epsilon.

Comment: The most common "general" way to approach this is to make the "epsilon" be some small fraction of the input numbers.  How small a faction depends on the amount of (in)accuracy presumed to be present, generally large enough to "ignore" one or two decimal places in the float representation.  Single `float` has about 7 digits, while `double` almost 16, so, roughly, the single epsilon would be about 0.00001 of number magnitude, while the double epsilon would be about 0.00000000000001 of magnitude, if I counted correctly.

Comment: @HotLicks: The common “general” way is wrong. Please do not advise it. The “epsilon” you describe is approximately the rounding error in a **single** calculation. Sequences of numerical computations do not obey any rule of proportionality; errors compound in complex and non-linear ways. The final error in a sequence of computations may be not proportional to the final finals and may be infinite or non-numeric.

Comment: @EricPostpischil - No, the rounding error in a single calculation would be essentially one binary bit.  Two decimal places allows for a "normal" situation with several computations (and no "problematic" computations such as subtracting two very similar numbers).

Comment: @HotLicks: The common “general” way is wrong. Please do not advise it. Estimating some slop for the error is useful only for school exercises. It breaks in the real world and should not be suggested as a method to use in real-world code.

Comment: Note: “final finals” in a previous comment was intended to be “final values”.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no library routine for this, and there cannot be because there is no general way of comparing numbers containing errors that is suitable for all applications.

The kinds of errors that can occur in numerical calculations (whether floating-point or otherwise) include errors that are relative to some known final value, errors that are absolute or that are relative to some value other than the final value or even the input values, combinations of these, and more. The magnitudes of errors can range from zero to infinity or can even be non-numerical (when errors during calculation create NaNs).

In order to determine what error can be tolerated, it is essential to know what calculations were performed, what bounds there are on the input data and on intermediate values, and what harms will be caused by falsely accepting as equal two numbers that would not be equal if computed exactly and, conversely, by falsely rejecting as equal two numbers that would be equal if computed exactly.

All of this is hugely application-specific, so it cannot be solved with a general library routine. The bulk of the work in solving this problem is analyzing the errors and judging the benefits and harms of potential choices. Once that work is done, the actual comparison is so easy (test whether the difference between the two numbers is within the interval judged to be acceptable) that little is accomplished by providing a library routine for it.

Some people approach this problem as “We do numerical calculations, we get some error, the error is caused by numerical rounding, not by the actual mathematics, so let’s ignore it.” But the actual problem is “This program computes **wrong numbers**; how do we get right answers from wrong numbers?”

In general, you cannot. There is no library routine that accepts wrong numbers as arguments and returns correct answers as results.

In conclusion, you have to look at your code and the numbers you are working with and figure out what errors you can accept.

Comment: I've edited my question to address your objections. I agree, the library should not choose the epsilon for me (maybe, just maybe a sensible default...). But I might be able to provide it when I call the comparison function.

Comment: There is a branch of mathematics that analyzes computations to compute the error.  Rearranging the order of operations can often make a big difference, and even if the computations are assumed to be "perfect" it's useful to consider how measurement inaccuracies, etc, propagate through, and how to minimize that propagation.

Comment: @Timo: Even if your particular problem can be solved by providing a tolerance (“epsilon” is a poor term, as it may be confused with “machine epsilon” and with mathematical use of epsilon for a vanishing error), this is not a general solution. As my answer indicates, various numerical calculations might produce errors that vary based on numerous factors, so that a single tolerance for an entire array might not be suitable. Good libraries do not have a general routine for this because it is not a good general solution. Take the guidance from this: This is not a good method.

Comment: @Timo: The correct approach is application-specific. The form you ask for, a function that operates on two objects, returns true or false, and is null-safe, is simply a wrapper and is not hugely worthy of making into a library routine. The bulk of the work is in figuring out what comparison you need, what differences you can accept as almost equal. (And, if you need a true equivalence relation, equality must be transitive; you cannot use any “almost equals” for this purpose.)

Comment: For clarity. I know my domain object will finally be truncated to 4 decimals. So for equality's sake I could compare two instances and use a tolerance of 0.0001. Additionally the domain object is a data object, I do all the computations and these are under my control. I know the tolerance that I need when I call the equals method. Without this tolerance I am essentially comparing the representation of my actual value and I **know** this will eventually break my tests. Equality (and transitivity) in the implementation are not the same as equality in the domain. And it is the latter that I want.

Comment: And: I do not want the library to determine the tolerance! **I** want to code it in.

Comment: @Timo: So, to summarize your comments, you want to compare multiple objects using one tolerance even though this is not a general solution for other applications, you want a comparison for equality that does not serve as equality in general use, and you want to perform comparisons that will eventually break your tests. And you want this code in a library routine. I think if you reflect upon these requirements, you will see why it is a bad idea to package certain specific ill-advised operations into a library routine. Library routines should be high-quality code for general use.

Comment: @Timo: So, it is too bad if you do not like the answer, but it is correct: This is not a good fit for a library routine. If you want to do it, you will have to write your own code. It does not seem like it would be a great deal of code, so surely you could write it easily and be done with it.

Comment: @EricPostpischil I can agree with most of the things you say. I cannot help that you seem to pick up on the most negative aspects of the question. This might partly be caused by the lack of context that I can (and/or have) give(n) you here. However I also have the feeling that you do not want to see what my need is and why I feel that this could be a library function. So let me try one more time:

Comment: I believe that this is suitable as a library function because I have to check for equality in different object types (NB two instances are always of the same class, not cross-class (which is nonsense)). These checks have to give consistent results based on the domain value, not the implementation value. My control flow should run on domain values, not on implementation values. However I do not control how the domain values are stored. So I am trying to find a way that will guarantee that it does not matter how these values are stored as long as the domain value I calculated is still in there.

Comment: The method declaration I specified in my question was partly meant to make this more clear.
Given an instance of `SomeObject` with 10.5000000001
And an instance of `SomeObject` with 10.49999999999
When I compare the two instances with a tolerance 0.1,
Then these instances are equal.

Where my When clause would translate to
`Util.equals(o1, o2, 0.1);`

Comment: @Timo: I have to wonder if you have misunderstood what a library is, when you asked “Is there a library available for JAVA that does this already?” A library is collection of routines provided for reuse by multiple independent programs. That is why I have been emphasizing that this code is not suitable for a library: You are asking for bad hacks for your specific application, and they do not belong in a library to be used by other people. If you merely want a template or a routine to use in your own application, that is a different matter. Still, why do you not simply write the code you want?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/45127/discussion-between-timo-and-eric-postpischil)

Comment: This is the answer to my question, there is no library function. The discussion that followed is about why it does not exist. I am aware that I could implement this myself, but I would have preferred a library to handle all the details.

Answer (score 0):

The `equals` relation is required to be transitive.  This implies that unless all numbers compare equal, there's no way to avoid the existence of two numbers which differ only infinitesimally but compare as different.

It may be helpful to have objects define equality in terms of rounded values (round the values independently, and then check if they're equal), but if e.g. a collection stores values rounded to the nearest integer and one wants to find things that are within 0.1 of `value`, one should search for both `value+0.1` and `value-0.1` [if they both round to the same integer, one only need search for one].  If the item exists in the collection, one of those searches will find it.  It may also find items which are more than 0.1 units away, but one can examine the items one finds and simply reject any which aren't close enough.

Answer (score 0):

Make your object implement an interface called ComparableByTolerance, with a method called getFloat (or similar). You now decide how that object gives it's float.

Make a class called ToleranceUtils

```
public static class TolerenceUtils {
public float tolerance =0;
public void setTolerance( float tolerance) {
 this.tolerance =tolerance;
  }
public boolean toleranceCompare(ComparableByTolerance objectWithFloat1,ComparableByTolerance objectWithFloat2){
    (objectWithFloat1.getFloat() - objectWithFloat2.getFloat())<=tolerance;
}

}
```

That way you can specify the tolerance when you compare the two.

Comment: Better to make tolerance a function of parm magnitude.

Comment: @HotLicks so it becomes 10^-n?

Comment: Some small fraction of abs(myFloat1), eg.

Comment: This does not answer my question. I wanted to compare Objects that contain a floating point value. This allows me to compare floating point values. Thank you for the attempt :)

Comment: @Pureferret I stated in my question that I cannot modify my domain objects (I would have changed the equals function to work according to the specified precision). This also means that I cannot make them implement the interface.